# How do I save a question when I have to wait to be able to ask?

Tags: support, asking-questions

If I'm not allowed to ask a question for another day or two, how do I save a question or 'queue' it?

Comment: Open your text editor of choice, just like you would for any other text data you want to save.

Comment: In theory, a draft is saved for new questions and should be kept for one week. However, better not rely on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your draft should be saved automatically. If you are using the StackExchange Application, you are able to edit your draft by clicking the button to create new questions. You will be asked either to discard or to continue.